# Increase stack size to use alloca()?

Tags: c++, c, performance, memory, memory-management

This is two questions overlapping- I wish to try out alloca() for large arrays instead of assigning dynamically-sized arrays on the heap. This is so that I can increase performance without having to make heap allocations. However, I get the impression stack sizes are usually quite small? Are there any disadvantages to increasing the size of my stack so that I can take full advantage of alloca()? Is it The more RAM I have, the larger I can proportionally increase my stack size?

EDIT1: Preferably Linux

EDIT2: I don't have a specified size in mind- I would rather know how to judge what determines the limit/boundaries.

Comment: One drawback of `alloca` is that it doesn't detect allocation failures; if you try allocate too much stack space, the behavior is undefined and your program will probably crash.

Comment: @KeithThompson - with Linux `malloc` is no better really, it pretty much always returns a valid pointer as long as you request an amount within the full address space. In a test recently, I was able to request 137435723384 kB successfully before I got a NULL back (!).

Comment: @teppic: That's the default behavior on Linux. But you can turn on conformant (that is, "sane") behavior if you wish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack sizes are (by default) 8MB on most unix-y platforms, and 1MB on Windows (namely, because Windows has [a deterministic way for recovering from out of stack problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082.aspx), while unix-y platforms usually throw a generic `SIGSEGV` signal).

If your allocations are large, you won't see much of a performance difference between allocating on the heap versus allocating on the stack. Sure, the stack is slightly more efficient per allocation, but if your allocations are large the number of allocations is likely to be small.

If you want a larger stack-like structure you can always write your own allocator which obtains a large block from malloc and then handles allocation/deallocation in a stack-like fashion.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstddef>

class StackLikeAllocator
{
    std::size_t usedSize;
    std::size_t maximumSize;
    void *memory;
public:
    StackLikeAllocator(std::size_t backingSize)
    {
        memory = new char[backingSize];
        usedSize = 0;
        maximumSize = backingSize;
    }
    ~StackLikeAllocator()
    {
        delete[] memory;
    }
    void * Allocate(std::size_t desiredSize)
    {
        // You would have to make sure alignment was correct for your
        // platform (Exercise to the reader)
        std::size_t newUsedSize = usedSize + desiredSize;
        if (newUsedSize > maximumSize)
        {
            throw std::bad_alloc("Exceeded maximum size for this allocator.");
        }

        void* result = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<char*>(memory) + usedSize);
        usedSize = newUsedSize;
        return result;
    }

    // If you need to support deallocation then modifying this shouldn't be
    // too difficult
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that last paragraph please?

Comment: If you run into a stack overflow on Windows, what are your options after observing the exception? You don't get the stack enlarged for you automatically and doing that manually is going to get you a discontinuous stack, with which your program is unlikely to be able to continue to work anyway.

Comment: @Alexy: You can't continue the code that caused the overflow, no. But you can deterministically keep the process from being destroyed and/or report a reasonable "out of memory" error code to clients if you are a library. For instance, `boost::regex`'s default regex executor is stack based, and on Windows they catch `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW` and use that to bail out of the regex becomes pathological.

Comment: So, that's not quite a recovery then, it's detection.

Comment: @Alexey: I would call "the process is not destroyed" recovery. Yes, you can run out of stack. But that's the case for any allocation strategy. You can get `std::bad_alloc`, and you can't "resume" from that either. It works the same way.

Comment: @Alexey: Put another way, "recovery" does not necessarily mean "resume." If you need a larger stack size pretty much every platform I know of allows you to ask for it.

Comment: @BillyONeal Excellent- I will have a read of this over the day! I have a question- is stack usage always faster than heap usage? An answer below suggests stack allocation would be quicker, but "filling, reading and manipulating" would be slower? I thought stack usage would always be faster because the memory is closer to access?

Comment: @Mezamorphic: No that's not true. Yes, it is likely that the stack is in the CPU's cache because the stack is being accessed constantly. There's nothing "special" about the stack in comparison to any other memory block. As [Johannes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15626936) indicates below though, if your data is large enough that your stack loses cache locality then your overall program may be slower. The primary reason that the stack may be faster in some cases is just that it has little memory management overhead. Because memory is used in a FIFO order, the overhead can be as small as a pointer

Comment: @Mezamorphic: Put another way, general purpose heaps have to deal with arbitrary allocation/deallocation patterns, and do well for the majority of workloads. If your program has a data structure which is okay with the far simpler stack allocation strategy, then your memory manager overhead (both space and time) can be less. But probably not *hugely* less.

Comment: @BillyONeal I think I get you- at the end of the day the stack is just a structure. This structure can still make the cache temporal/spatial locality worse..... What is the best way to think about the structure of a heap? Like a hashmap?

Comment: @mezamorphic: Heaps are complicated beasts. The best explanation I've ever seen of one was in [the Seacord book](http://www.amazon.com/Secure-Coding-Edition-Software-Engineering/dp/0321822137/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1364334249&sr=8-2&keywords=Robert+Seacord) which goes into the details of the most common Unix-y allocator (`dlmalloc`) as well as Windows' `RtlHeap` library.

Answer (score 4):

The default stack size that the main thread of a program gets is a compiler-specific (and/or OS-specific) thing and you should see the appropriate documentation to find out how to enlarge the stack.

It may happen that you may be unable to enlarge the program's default stack to an arbitrarily large size.

You may, however, as it's been pointed out, be able to create a thread at run time with a stack of the size you want.

In any event, there's not much benefit of `alloca()` over a once allocated large buffer. You don't need to free and reallocate it many times.

Comment: The stack size is not compiler specific. The compiler does not know anything about the stack size.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann Oh, really? Borland/Turbo C/C++ has the variable named `_stklen` that is initialized with the stack size. The `PE` image format has two fields in it: `STACK RESERVE SIZE` and `STACK COMMIT SIZE` and that's what Microsoft's C/C++ compiler generates.

Comment: @Alexey: It probably just gives the default stack size then. A user can call `CreateThread` with whatever stack size they want and that's what you'll get, regardless of what the compiler thinks.

Comment: @BillyONeal That's a different stack, created at run time. And we don't know whether creating a thread at run time for the purpose of having a big enough stack is applicable.

Comment: @Alexey: That doesn't change that the compiler doesn't ultimately choose what the stack size is. The platform does that.

Comment: @BillyONeal The compiler often chooses the default stack's size.

Comment: @Alexey: A program cannot increase its own stack size beyond the (usually quite low) limit imposed by the OS.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann - in Linux a process can, by default, request an unlimited stack size.

Comment: @teppic: And in every other POSIX compliant or Windows platform of which I am aware :)

Comment: @BillyONeal - ah ok, I only knew it was true for Linux.

Comment: +1 -- this is a good answer. (Sorry for forgetting to do that before)

Answer (score 3):

The most important difference between `alloca()` and `new` / `malloc()` is that all memory allocated with `alloca()` will be gone when you return from the current function.

`alloca()` is only useful for small temporary data structures.

It is only useful for small data structures since big data structures will destroy the cache locality of your stack which will give you a rather big performance hit. The same goes for arrays as local variables.

Use `alloca()` only in very specific circumstances. If unsure, do not use it at all.

The general rule is: Do not put big data structures (>= 1k) on the stack. The stack does not scale. It is a very limited resource.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first question: The stack size is typically small relative to the heap size (this would hold true in most Linux applications).

If the allocations you are planning are large *relative* to the actual default stack size, then I think it would be better to use dynamic allocation from the heap (rather than trying to increase stack sizes).  The cost of using the memory (filling it, reading it, manipulating it) is probably going to far exceed the cost of the allocation.  It is unlikely that you would see a measurable benefit by allocating from the stack in this scenario.